# How to keep small images on Google Drive from counting against my storage limit?

Tags: google-drive

It appears Google has recently changed it so that everyone gets up to 15GB of storage divided between GMail and all the other apps such as Google Drive, but images below a certain size (800x800 pixels if you don't have Google+) are mentioned as not counting below your storage limit.  However I uploaded a bunch of 500x500 images as a test and they are definitely counting against the limit.  A bit of further research suggests [pictures uploaded by Google Drive are counted](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375194?hl=en), although I couldn't find why this is since the same images when uploaded by Picasa Web are not and they are both going to Google.

I also have read that Google Drive images can be shared with Google+, although there is no mention of whether or not or how the small image exclusion works there either.  But it also seems to be suggested that [Google+ pictures up to 2048x2048 are also not counted against the limit](https://www.google.com/settings/storage), so I'm confused about how this works if you send the pictures for Google+ via Google Drive.

At the moment I only have Google Drive - the desktop client - I do not have Google+ or Picasa.  That's the way I would like to keep it unless it's absolutely necessary to have one of the others in order to get unlimited small image uploads via Google Drive.   Do I simply need to sign up for Google+, and then small images uploaded via Drive automatically stop counting against my storage limit, or do I have to add the step to share them with Google+, or do I have to actually use something outside of Google Drive to upload them, meaning I don't have the easy of seeing the pictures on my desktop and have to go through the web interface?

Update: Ok, it appears that Picasa Web has been transitioning to Google Photos which is really Google+ Photos, although I still only see my pictures in Picasa Web as I haven't "upgraded" to Google+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a Google rep I talked to, the answer to this question is, "you can't".  Any images in Google+ that don't count against your storage limit will as soon as Google Drive can see them.